# Unable to load csv file into postgres table in heroku -Error :invalid input syntax for type integer:

Tags: python, csv, django-models, sqlbulkcopy, heroku-postgres

```
Error in copying db  invalid input syntax for type integer: "0"
CONTEXT:  COPY spellbeeword_tb, line 1, column id: "0"
```

My code:

```
import os
import psycopg2

def writedb(conn):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    print("Started opening file to copy into table")

    try:
        with  open("spellbee/docs/Spell_Bee_Word_db.csv", 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
            sql_copy= "COPY spellbeeword_tb  FROM stdin (FORMAT CSV)"
            cur.copy_expert(sql=sql_copy,file=f)
            print('successfully copied files into db')
            # commit changes
            conn.commit()
            print("Committed changes")
    
    except Exception as error:
        print('Error in copying db ',error)
    finally:
        if conn:
            conn.close()
            f.close()

def main():

    DATABASE_URL = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']

    

    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL, sslmode='require')
        
        
        writedb(conn)

    except(Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(error)
    finally:
        if conn:
            conn.close()

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    main()


    operations = [
            migrations.CreateModel(
                name='BeeWord',
                fields=[
                    ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                    ('level', models.CharField(max_length=10)),
                    ('word', models.CharField(max_length=90)),
                ],
 

operations = [
    migrations.AlterModelTable(
        name='beeword',
        table='spellbeeword_tb',
    ),
```

```
> 0 ONE gel
> 1 ONE day
> 2 ONE scorch
```

It is throwing error on above sample csv data.
It is not accepting integer value as given by csv I tried giving last two columns excluding Index from csv. Both way it is not accepting. Please provide solution.
Csv file contains only data without header. My ORM looks like above.

Comment: Are you sure the csv column has only integer values? It's possible some rows have strings because of which the whole column is being treated as string.

Comment: Had already deployed the same file in sqlite3  in dev region -local server .Now i tried to move the same into heroku environment</br> Since heroku doesn't support sqlite3, remotely I am pushing into Postgres db where I used copy_from . I tried copy_expert also. Postgres behave differently . I used camel case in my database table. But same thing doesn't work for postgres . Hence I renamed the table name . Then it works. So is there any workaround to solve this issue

Comment: There is no string in the Index column. I can incur onething from the error is that csv data extracted by cur.copy_expert  method ass string eventhough wee pass numbers. But this is not the case in sqlite3. </br> In the errror  type integer: "0" - zero is displayed within double quotes. How to read csv formatted file correctly?

Answer (score 0):

COPY command generates a header line which is being read by the import command as data.

tell the import command to not read the first line.

To avoid the header line generation , i dont know how to omit by default

To ignore the header line insert the HEADER option in the import command and also inserted header in the csv file as well. Now it worked fine

```
try:
        with  open("spellbee/docs/Spell_Bee_Word_db.csv", 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
            #cur.copy_from(f,'spellbeeword_tb', sep=',')
            sql_copy ="COPY spellbeeword_tb  FROM STDIN WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER ',' "
            cur.copy_expert(sql=sql_copy,file=f)
            print('successfully copied files into db')
            # commit changes
            conn.commit()
            print("Committed changes")
    
    except Exception as error:
        print('Error in copying db ',error)
    finally:
        if conn:
            conn.close()
            print("Finally connection closed")
            f.close()
```